# Draggable Image to Input Field

Tags: javascript, html, image, file-upload

I have a page which displays images in boxes, and they are draggable images. I also have input file upload fields. The goal is the user should be able to drag images to the input file upload field.

Is that possible? I am trying to prevent users from downloading the images in their local pc and then clicking the input file to select the image. So it's more if a user experience to reduce the steps. Basically the page will be a series of maybe 10 images of clothes. And then I have 5 input file fields which has a label of  (front,back,logo etc.). So basically assigning an image base on  the label of the input file field.

I am searching and can't seem to find anything like this, or is there another way to approach this?

Here's the fiddle file that I have so far:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col overflow-auto" style="height: 213px; border: 1px solid red; padding: 5px;" id="image_list" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
    <img height="100" width="100" src="https://image.shutterstock.com/image-vector/sample-stamp-grunge-texture-vector-260nw-1389188336.jpg" draggable="true" id="10-0" style="border: 1px solid black;">

    <img height="100" width="100" src="https://image.shutterstock.com/image-vector/sample-stamp-grunge-texture-vector-260nw-1389188336.jpg" draggable="true" id="10-0" style="border: 1px solid black;">
</div>
```

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="title">Front *</label>
    <input type="file" id="front_image" name="front_image" accept="image/*">
</div>
```

Comment: You're loading some images on your page, and then you want your users to upload those images back to your server? Notice, that the images are already downloaded to the user's PC when the img tags have loaded the images, you can't prevent that.

Comment: @Teemu the images that they will put into input file will go another server. Actually an API endpoint. yes i understand that. just wondering how they can drag those images into an input file without clicking it and selecting images in their local disk.

Comment: OK, I've slightly missunderstood the question. Anyway, you can't drop an image from the page to `input type="file"`. Create ["droppable"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTML_Drag_and_Drop_API/Drag_operations) divs instead, then create ex. blobs from the images, and send the blobs to that other server using AJAX. Or perhaps send just the URLs, that other server can then load the images from your server when needed ..?